# Node Axios module PUT request with custom HTTP headers and data

Tags: node.js, axios, put

I want to send a PUT request to an endpoint that creates an ElasticSearch index. Using the Axios NPM module for that. How do I send a request for different REST verbs with data as well as custom headers.

```
const options = {
hostname: "c1-es03c.aue2l.internal",
port: 9200,
path: "/",
method: "PUT",
rejectUnauthorized: true,
requestCert: true,
servername: "c1-elasticsearch.internal",
ca: [fs.readFileSync("./Root-CA.pem")],
headers: {
"Authorization": "Basic xxxxx"
}
req.write("{data here}");
req.end();
var req = https.request(options, callback)
```

HTTPS module works fine, how do I do the same with axios or request.

axios.put(url, options, data) didn't work.

Comment: The method signature for axios is `.put(url, data, options)`

Answer (score 0):

You can install axios using '$ npm install axios' command. You can easily understand by this typescript code. For more information you can use this link,
[Axios npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios)

```
const axios = require('axios');

export class RequestContext {

    constructor() { }

    post(request: any, response: any): void {

        let header = {
            "Content-type": "application/json"
        }
        let data = request.data;
        axios.put(url, data, header).then((result) => {
        \\ .then() methord is use when you want to process on data that return from API.
            console.log(result)
        })
    }
}
```